# Copy row from Master List if Column D contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

pretty new to VBA so i could use some help with this one, as I have been struggling all morning with it. I have a Master List and in column D, there are words like "1x Daily" and "1x Month." My goal is that whatever it says in that column, it gets put in the respective new sheet. So in this case if D2 = "1x Daily" then the entire row gets copied into the sheet that is entitled "1x Daily"

Below is my recent try, but will not work for various reasons i'm assuming, but its the best attempt I came up with

```
Sub Test()
  For Each Cell In Sheet(1).Range("D:D")
    If Cell.Value = "1x Daily AM" Then
      matchRow = Cell.Row
      Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
      Selection.Copy

      Sheets("1x Daily All").Select
      ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      Sheets("Master Vitals Data").Select
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Edit, when I am in the editor and trying to run the code, I get the error message "Compile error.  Sub or function not defined"

Comment: What problems are you facing with this code?

Comment: Please include the error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution which might work even better for you:

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub TestRevised()

Dim cell As Range
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim sheetNames() As String
Dim lngItem As Long, lngLastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet, shtMaster As Worksheet

'Set master sheet
Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Vitals Data")

'Get the names for all other sheets
ReDim sheetNames(0)
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> shtMaster.Name Then
        sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames)) = sht.Name
        ReDim Preserve sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames) + 1)
    End If
Next sht
ReDim Preserve sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames) - 1)

For Each cell In shtMaster.Range("D1:D" & shtMaster.Cells(shtMaster.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    bolFound = False
    For lngItem = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
        If cell.Value2 = sheetNames(lngItem) Then
            bolFound = True
            Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNames(lngItem))
            On Error GoTo SetFirst
            lngLastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
            On Error GoTo 0
            shtMaster.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(lngLastRow, 1)
        End If
    Next lngItem
    If bolFound = False Then
        For Each cmt In shtMaster.Comments
            If cmt.Parent.Address = cell.Address Then cmt.Delete
        Next cmt
        cell.AddComment "no sheet found for this row"
    End If
Next

Exit Sub

SetFirst:
    lngLastRow = 1
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Essentially, this code first gathers all the sheet names in the Excel file and then compares them to the cell content in column `D` for each row. If there is a sheet for *whatever is written in column D* then the row is copied over. Like this you can have not only monthly or weekly sheets. But also daily or biweekly or yearly sheets. Furthermore, this code adds a comment to the rows which didn't get transferred as not appropriate sheet has been found. Like this you can immediately see if the spelling for one sheet is off.

The following screencast is a short demonstration of the code:

[image]

<sub>Note, that the sheet for the master sheet (containing all the data to transfer) must coincide with the name given in the code. Otherwise, VBA doesn't know where to transfer the data from. Also note, that the line with sheet6 first doesn't get transferred as there is not sheet for it. But as soon as I create a new sheet with the name sheet6 the code words fine and also transfers this line.</sub>

Comment: I am getting a "run time error 9, sub out of range" error message. Any idea what that means?

Also where do I type the names for all other sheets?

Comment: I added a screencast. Hope that helps you understand the code and the given solution. Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Ralph, One question with the code. Every time I run the code, it adds the cells to the sheet (which is a good thing) but it doesnt override what was previously there. So I end up with it getting repeated in the sheet. I found someone on another thread that said "application.match" could help solve that problem but I dont quite understand where to use that, or if it would work. Would you be able to provide some insight?

Comment: How do you want to `match` the rows from the `master sheet` with the rows from the other sheet? Is there something which is 100% unique about these rows that cannot repeat and can therefore be used as a unique identifier (for each and any row in your Excel file)? If that's the case then you might be able to use `Match` for that purpose. But that's a new question and you should post it as such. Just make sure that you include all the necessary information (including the info I just asked for).

Comment: Yes each row is unique and therefore cannot be repeated. I posted the new updated question, thank you for all the help you have given me.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious problem with your code is that you're not moving the selection after pasting. In the target sheet, you should move to next row after pasting one. Otherwise each new paste operation will overwrite the previous paste.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use selection and selection.copy, it will cause you a lot of trouble, just declare everything before starting to operate with range and use the Range Class method to copy/paste to another sheet previously declared, so there is no need to move "around sheet" to copy and paste like a human will do. Let's start to think as computer, he already have in his memory everything he need to work on, so use it!

I advise you to declare every object before starting to write code in VBA so you can get the property and method of that object (with the intellisense, just do a point after the object name and VBA will show you everything you need), ex. the Range object have a "COPY" method that have a *DESTINATION* parameter as rangee too that you can use to move range from a point to another.

Here's the example in your case:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()
    'SPECIFY OPTION EXPLICIT TO DON'T MISS ANY DECLARATION
    Dim ws_Master As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'range to iterate
    Dim cell As Range 'cell for iteration
    Dim ws_1xDaily As Worksheet 'Worksheet for daily data
    Dim ws_1xMonthly As Worksheet 'Worksheet for monthly data

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 'Integer for parsing
    'END DECLARATION

    'Sheets and range object creation

    Set ws_Master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Vitals Data")
    Set rng = ws_Master.Range("D1:D" & ws_Master.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)  'This will get the last row of the Range D:D so we can iterate until last row
    Set ws_1xDaily = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1x Daily All")
    Set ws_1xMonthly = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1x Monthly All")

    'End

    'That's all you have to do now is just copy a range to another range, just few line of code in a for each loop:

    i = 1 'to remember the last row we used in the daily sheet
    j = 1 'same as before but for the monthly sheet
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "1x Daily AM" Then cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws_1xDaily.Range("A" & i): i = i + 1
        If cell.Value = "1x Monthly" Then cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws_1xMonthly.Range("A" & j): j = j + 1
    Next cell

    'End

End Sub
```

If you wont to be more efficient you could use the .Find method of the Range Object to find every cell that contains what you are searching for, in the "D:D" range, without specifying the last row and without iterating empty cell too, go to take a look at that method!

Here it is the example for the daily events with the .Find method:

```
Sub test2()
    'SPECIFY OPTION EXPLICIT TO DON'T MISS ANY DECLARATION
    Dim ws_Master As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'range to iterate
    Dim cell As Range 'cell for iteration
    Dim ws_1xDaily As Worksheet 'Worksheet for daily data
    Dim ws_1xMonthly As Worksheet 'Worksheet for monthly data
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim toCopyRng As Range
    'END DECLARATION

    'Sheets and range object creation

    Set ws_Master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Vitals Data")
    Set rng = ws_Master.Range("D:D")
    Set ws_1xDaily = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1x Daily All")
    Set ws_1xMonthly = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1x Monthly All")

    i = 1 'to remember the last row we used in the daily sheet
    Set toCopyRng = rng.Find("1x Daily AM", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not toCopyRng Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = toCopyRng.Address
        Do
            toCopyRng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws_1xDaily.Range("A" & i): i = i + 1 'copy and increment row of the daily sheet
            Set toCopyRng = rng.FindNext(toCopyRng)
        Loop While Not toCopyRng Is Nothing And toCopyRng.Address <> firstAddress
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: exSnake, thank you for responding. I am getting the error message on the first code saying runtime error '9' subscript out of range. What does that refer to? again i am brand new to this so everything is very foreign

Comment: it's the sheet name, probably isn't "Master Vitals Data" you have to set it, the same thing happen if the daily sheet isn't called "1x Daily All"